# Confused on how SMB (1.0) and Mapped I/O work together

Tags: memory-mapped-files, smb, internals

I'm trying to get some more detailed Information on mapped I/O and a SMB(1)-Share.

I discovered a scenario, where an application, which starts from a network-share throws an In-Page error(0xc0000006) with status code 0xc000020c (STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED).

The strange thing is, that even if the connection was eventually broken, it is working at the moment.

The only way to get it working again, is to shut down every process, which is using the dll and clear the standby-list.

Seems like there is no working "reconnect" implemented when doing mapped I/O over SMB, or did i get something wrong?

Would be nice if anyone could point me to some information on how these things work in-depth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i know there is no "reconnect" over SMBv1.
If you want to continue to work on the file list that you already open, after the reconnect you need to reopen them again (in the app level).
The connection could be reestablished but all the file handles in the server are gone.

The reconnect feature is implemented starting from SMBv2.